# jquery libraries and js clashing

Tags: jquery, libraries

Im in the process of coding a parallax design simply html css and js... Im using a load of js files, and have no idea what to do to stop the conflict. One set of the libraries seems to influencing the parallax effect and the other is a tabbed panel. Heres the code

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs().addClass( "ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix" );
    $( "#tabs li" ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-left" );
  });
  </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
```

When I remove this line the parallax effect breaks and the tabbed panel works, vice versa... When this line is present the CSS of the tabbed panel seems to disappear for some reason?

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Ive uploaded it live for you to look at... http://owen-walters.com/meetmax/ (its a work in progress!!!!, at the moment its the parallax effect thats working and the tabbed panel is broken.. but look at the image I've uploaded to see what it should look like.

Any sort of suggestions would be awesome!!!!

Comment: You can't just blindly install both jQuery version 1.7.2 and version 1.9.1.  You either need to find one version of jQuery that works for everything or you have to very carefully code in order to use multile versions of jQuery at the same time.  How to do that depends upon exactly which other pieces of code need which version of jQuery so that information would be required in order to help with that solution.  You can read about how to do that with `jQuery.noConflict()`.  Finding a way to use only one version of jQuery is the preferred solution if possible.

Comment: jQuery uses and stores it's library in `$` as a variable name. To use your other jQuery version you need to dump it into another variable name ;)